# ASP.NET MVC Unit Testing RedirectResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a class that inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult` which overrides `ExecuteResult`. How do I unit test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you override does.

In general, mock `HttpContextBase`, create the necessary `RouteData` and use those two elements to create a `ControllerContext`.

Instantiate your custom `RedirectResult`, call `ExecuteResult` passing in your previously created `ControllerContext` and then make assertions on the various bits and pieces that you mocked.

If you want a more comprehensive answer, I would need more details as to exactly what your override does.